# Angular2 Material errors in webpack when importing MaterialModule

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-material

I am following the steps from the getting started page
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

So far I have installed material with the following

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Now I am attempting to import the MaterialModule into my app component

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Which causes webpack to throw a ton of errors like

```
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:14:27 
';' expected.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:14:29 
Duplicate identifier 'string'.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:15:4 
Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:15:13 
'=' expected.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:15:13 
Cannot find name '_tabindex'.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:15:22 
';' expected.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-item.d.ts:15:24 
Duplicate identifier 'string'.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-trigger.d.ts:26:4 
Duplicate identifier 'readonly'.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-trigger.d.ts:26:13 
'=' expected.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-trigger.d.ts:26:13 
Cannot find name 'menuOpen'.
ERROR in [default] C:/mypathSource/Repos/dir/Web.Angular/node_modules/@angular/material/menu/menu-trigger.d.ts:26:21 
';' expected.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating all the versions of my node modules by coping the package.json from the angular/webpack starter kit and the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

After importing the `MaterialModule` from the angular/material library, you'll need to add that import to the `NgModule` like so:

(in the same ts file you have imported the `MaterialModule`):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
```

That will add that Module so you can use it in your app.

Comment: Issue was related to webpack/typescript/node module configuration. Updated to latest Angular webpack starter kit and errors went away

Comment: @Josh, you need to either provide and accept an answer or delete your question so this post can be resolved.